# Adding processed class attribute to mapping to get a Model's list of columns from class_mapper introspection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How could I get the list of a Model's columns (and later of id columns, and relationships) as:

```
columns = Model.cols_list
```

so that the list would be constructed one time and reused when needed.

I would have writen something like this, that I can't get to work :

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import class_mapper

class Model(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'model_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    col1 = Column(...)
    col2 = Column(...)
    ...

    cols_list = None

    @classmethod
    def cols_list(cls):
        if cls.cols_list is None:
            cls.cols_list = [key.name for key in class_mapper(cls).primary_key]
        return cls.cols_list
```

Comment: Did you try `Model.__table__.columns`?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Model(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'model_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    col1 = Column(...)
    col2 = Column(...)

    @classmethod
    def col_list(cls):
        mapper = inspect(cls)
        return mapper.columns  

    @classmethod
    def relationships(cls):
        mapper = inspect(cls)
        return mapper.relationships
```

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapper_config.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.columns

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapper_config.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.column_attrs

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapper_config.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.relationships

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapper_config.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.attrs

etc.